# Why don't Octave or Matlab use % (percent symbol) as a modulo operator

Tags: matlab, octave

Someone new to the language might reasonably expect `7%4` to return `3`, i.e. the result of `mod(7,4)`, as it does in many other languages. Instead it returns `7` - "Why is this so?" s/he may ask...

Comment: The `why` is not a practical answerable question.

Comment: It's hard to explain this any better than the explanation MATLAB gives you. Type `why %` into MATLAB and you'll see exactly why this is.

Comment: I actually wrote this question as someone returning to octave/matlab after not using it for a while and I assumed that `%` would be the modulo operator and it caused me a bug, so I tried to write a question and answer that would match the types of searches I then made, such as: "octave modulus operator", "why is % not the modulo operator" just so others could find their answer quicker than it took me to remember that `%` is a comment delimiter. Would people prefer I edit it to say "what is the modulo operator in octave"? I think Dan's answer is interesting nonetheless...

Comment: Also as you may have deduced I wasn't taking this question very seriously :) Oh btw @RobertP. what does `why %` return? I don't have access to the Matrix Laboratory at this time...

Answer (score 13):

Why should you *reasonably* expect `7%4` to return `3`? `%` isn't a mathematical symbol for the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). If you read the Wikipedia article, you'll see that as many languages use `mod` as use `%` so Matlab isn't an odd one out here. It's just a different language from where ever you were coming from.

I would ***guess*** that `%` came from C and Matlab was initially aimed at 'competing' with Fortran rather than C. Fortran uses `MOD` and not `%`. I think the only reason you expect `%` to mean modulo is because of the influence of C and that [the question of why modulo gets a special operator character in many languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206293/why-is-mod-a-fundamental-mathematical-operator-in-many-programming-languages) is more relevant. Why modulo over floor for example? Or over absolute?

Matlab uses `%` for comments but that cannot be said to be the reason that it doesn't use it for modulo. I think that it's more fair to say the reason that it doesn't use `%` for modulo is because there really isn't any reason for it to.

Comment: Interesting point. I guess that almost all languages that people actually use (and pretty much all the non-lispy ones I've used - besides obviously Matlab/Octave): C, Java, Javascript, PHP, Python, Ruby, C# ... all use `%` for modulo so that's why I think many might _reasonably_ assume the use of `%` as modulo as fairly ubiquitous and I guess that's testament to C's influence. Nonetheless it is an interesting point you raise and is addressed in your programmers.stackexchange link. See my comment on the OQ as to why I actually posted this, in retrospect - ill posed, question.

Answer (score 8):

`%` is used for [comments](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Single-Line-Comments.html) in Matlab. The correct syntax in Octave/Matlab for finding the remainder after division (i.e. the modulo operation) is to use the [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function.

e.g.

```
>> mod(8,3)

ans = 

     2
```

Comment: This is really just [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question). Why does Matlab use `%` for comments?

Comment: It is true that `%` is used for comments, but there is absolutely no proof here that if that was not the case, the `%` sign would have been used for modulo. As such this answer is somewhere between insufficient and invalid.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I disagree, it's a perfectly valid answer, and one I would have given myself if it wasn't there already. Why `%` is use for comments and whether `%` would have been used for modulo if it wasn't used for comments is completely irrelevant, the point is `%` has a dedicated use in MATLAB, and that's for comments. Upvoting the answer.

Comment: @am304 You cannot logically conclude that the *reason* (i.e. the answer to *why*) `%` is not used for modulo is because it is used for comments. What makes you so sure that the design team didn't first assign operators (including modulo) and then choose a comment character from what was left. There is just as much chance that `%` is used as comments because it was *NOT* used for modulo. So I would say that this answer is not valid.

Comment: @Dan That's your prerogative, but I disagree. I persist in saying that the answer is valid.

Comment: @Dan am304 Early versions of MATLAB did not include a modulo function at all.

Comment: @Dan I agree that my answer to my own question doesn't soundly address the decisions behind why Matlab's designers chose to use `%` for comments and not, as is common, as a modulo operator, but it was good enough for me to put to bed my curiosity on the matter when I remembered it (see my comments on the OQ), so I think others may feel the same way. @am304 thanks for your unwavering support in these tumultuous times :)

Comment: @JobJob I would then at least remove the word 'because' from your answer and add a link and example syntax of how to correctly calculate a modulus in Matlab. If you can find a link ratifying what Sam Roberts has said, that would be very valuable evidence in favour of your argument.

Comment: @Dan Instead of removing the `Because` I added a smiley to reflect my how seriously I was taking it when originally posting this Q&A :)

Comment: @JobJob I've refined your answer and changed my -1 to a +1. Feel free to rollback if you disagree

Comment: I can live with it, yours is probably more informative, mine was possibly more entertaining, I'm happy if you're happy... :)